# Matlab nvcc clang unsupported option '-dumpspecs'

Tags: matlab, clang, gpu

When I try compiling the sample code from "Accelerating Matlab with GPUs. A Primer with Examples", I get the following errors:

```
>> nvcc -c AddVectors.cu
clang: error: unsupported option '-dumpspecs'
clang: error: no input files
```

Please help. I'm on a Mac with updated Xcode.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't you need to wrap it with a `system` call?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is. I'm just learning at this point

Comment: I meant - `system('nvcc -c AddVectors.cu')`

Comment: same error. Actually this error seems to persist with any cuda kernel; whenever I use nvcc